# Integrating CLIPS with a user interface

Tags: .net, interface, artificial-intelligence, clips

I am developing a project using [CLIPS](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/), the rules based system. I need to develop a good GUI as well for my project. Which language can be integrated with CLIPS? Can .NET be intergrated? Please suggest the languages which can be intergrated with the CLIPS engine.

Comment: does it answers the question?

Answer (score 0):

CLIPS provides a library in C that can be used by any language that can work with C libraries.

In the FAQ page of CLIPS there is this:
http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#Q8

The Clips .NET Lib integrates .NET and CLIPS. This library is distributed with source code.

Answer (score 0):

I've created some examples which demonstrate how to integrate a .NET Common Language Runtime wrapper around the native CLIPS code with Windows Forms and Windows Presentation Foundation projects. Information is available here: http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/CLIPSNETBeta.html